# checkbox size differ in some browser

Tags: html, css

I have this html defined where generating checkbox and label dynamically

```
 <div class="registrationFormOuter">     
<form role="form" [formGroup]="form">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6" *ngFor="let data of Field">
                                        <label class="blacklabel" [ngClass]="isCheckedTheme?'color-white':'color-black'">
                                            <input type="checkbox"style="width: 13px; height: 16.5px;" [value]="data">
                                            {{data.ques}}</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
</div>
```

and its css is

```
.registrationFormOuter{ padding: 15px 15px 0; min-height: 330px; 
    label{
        &.blacklabel{
            display:flex;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            align-items: flex-start;
            margin-bottom:10px;
            font-family: Google Sans,Roboto,Arial,sans-serif !important;
            font-size: 0.875rem !important;
            font-weight: 400 !important;
            letter-spacing: .0178571429em !important;
            text-transform: none  !important;
            input{
                margin-right:5px;
                margin-top:3px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Here some checkbox size differ in some browser but i have applied same css

Answer (score 0):

You can try using reset.css. The reset.css will help in making the CSS to look the same in all browsers

Use it from https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

```html
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Apply this globally before all css